# Is there a way for "force" the keyboard to dismiss in iOS Swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, dismiss

I have a `viewController` EditMessage which has two `UITextFields` (UITextView) which use the keyboard and they work great. This part is basic standard stuff. When the keyboard is displayed, I register a **tag gesture** for the entire `view`, so that if the user clicks anywhere else, I dismiss the keyboard:

```
 self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
         action: #selector(dismissKeyboard)))
```

In dismissKeyboard, this all works fine:

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard(sender: Any) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

However, I have a menu button(thumbnail image) implemented as a child view controller (`UIViewController`) on the same EditMessage view, which hijacks the screen via `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow()` to display an overlay and menu on the bottom of the screen. Built using the model/code from **Brian Voong's** YouTube channel to replicate a YouTube style slide in menu from the bottom. However, the keyboard is in the way. Since the child is a different view controller **"endEditing"** doesn't work (or maybe I am referencing the wrong view?).

```
class ButtonPickerController : UIViewController, 
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var maxSize = CGFloat(60)

let thumbnail: UIImageView = {
    let thumbnail = UIImageView()
    thumbnail.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return thumbnail
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped(sender:)))
    tap.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    //view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    thumbnail.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.maxSize, height: self.maxSize)
    setupSubviews()
}
```

Can someone point me in a good direction? This is my first question so hopefully I am asking properly.

Comment: self.view.endEditing(true) should work

Comment: use default method name **resignFirstResponder**. search for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resignFirstResponder vs. endEditing for Keyboard Dismissal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882775/resignfirstresponder-vs-endediting-for-keyboard-dismissal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dismiss keyboard iOS programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755410/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-ios-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the end. Thank you for the help. In my child view controller I did used the following statement when the button was tapped:

```
@objc func buttonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    self.parent!.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, its not a good way to present overlays as `UIViewController`.

But a solution good be, to give the second viewcontroller a reference to the first one before `viewDidLoad` is called. Do you use `Segue`s ? So in `prepare` would be the right place. In the second viewcontroller you create a property for the first one and then use this property as target when you create the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Another way is using a protocol and delegation.

Comment: I received the idea of using an overlay as UIViewController from the Apple Documentation. They recommend doing this when you have a collection of subviews you want to present, so that the code is cleaner.