# how to be able to do view.endEditing from UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell
and in it there is a reference to a UITextField:

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputTextSelectAnswer: UITextField!
```

i'm trying to add a "Done" button ontop of the keyboard and while u tap it the keyboard will be closed >

```
func setDoneOnKeyboard() {
        let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
        keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
        let flexBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        keyboardToolbar.items = [flexBarButton, doneBarButton]

        self.inputTextSelectAnswer.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
    }
```

since i don't call the UITextField in my controller itself, but in my UITableViewCell is there a way to dismiss the keyboard it throws an error

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
```

here is the code:

```
//CANNOT DO THE FUNCTION BELOW
    @objc override func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

how can this be done from a UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add that

```
weak var delegate:YourVC?
```

then inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.delegate = self
```

then

```
delegate?.view.endEditing(true)
```

---

Also you can use this directly inside the cell

```
self.endEditing(true)
```

> The UITableViewCell subclass doesn't contain a view property it's inside a UIViewController subclass

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the tool bar for a specific text field, calling [`resignFirstResponder()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621097-resignfirstresponder) would be more appropriate:

> Notifies this object that it has been asked to relinquish its status
>   as first responder in its window.

Keep in mind that it is related to the *window* of the text field, not a particular view, i.e you don't have to care about the `view` for end its editing in your case.

Call

```
inputTextSelectAnswer.resignFirstResponder()
```

when you are aiming to hide the keyboard the `inputTextSelectAnswer` text field.

**Furthermore:**

[resignFirstResponder vs. endEditing for Keyboard Dismissal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882775/resignfirstresponder-vs-endediting-for-keyboard-dismissal)